# how to open file from a folder with same name in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I need to run an executable file(Temp.exe) from "C:Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client" folder. The folder contains files with similar name as TempClientSetup.exml

I have this code

```
var path = @"C:\Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client";
var exepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "Temp.exe");
app = Application.Launch(exepath);
```

When I run this code, TempClientSetup.exml file is executed instead of Temp.exe

Any clues here? Pl suggest.

Comment: var exepath = Path.Combine(path, "Temp.exe");

Comment: put one more "\" to end in path...like "C:\Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client\"

Comment: @PranavPatel Idea of using `Path` class is to avoid doing all those OS specific things yourself. Your advice defeats the whole point.

Comment: let them check first...because i know it will wotk :D

Comment: @Pranav, sadly its not working and other suggestion too... :(

Comment: @shreevaze Are you sure you know what Application.Lauch() does?

Comment: @Matt Is that a default code from C#? When I searched I didn't find application.launch at all oO

Comment: Quite possible! @shreevaze What do you use to get "Application.Launch"? IS that part of a specific library? or something else?

Comment: hey guys, it worked now. The issue was something else. Internally from command line as well the path was not working indicating that the internal name of this file is same as Temp.exe :)

Comment: @Matt and thomas, yes Application.Launch is from TestStack.White library. But internally its using the same method of Process.StartInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick a slash on the end of the path, or get rid of the Path.GetDirectoryName call.

```
var path = @"C:\Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client\";
var exepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "Temp.exe");
```

or

```
var path = @"C:\Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client";
var exepath = Path.Combine(path, "Temp.exe");
```

Comment: Both of these solutions will give you the correct path to the exe you are trying to open.  I checked them before I posted them.  If you still aren't getting the correct file then that suggests that the file isn't there or your system is messed up in some way.
Please can you double check that the file is where you expect it?
also please debug the code and check that exepath has the correct value.  If it doesn't please post the value that it has to see if we can help further?

Comment: Worked fine for me now :) Thanks for your help Matt

Comment: Another tip for those who face this issue is, You may have to set the working directory of that exe to launch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question for those who face this issue is, You may have to set the working directory of that exe to launch ;-) like this

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"Temp.exe");
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\First Flight\Temp Client";            
app = Application.Launch(psi);
```